# Use of D flip-flop in Serial Adder

Tags: flipflop, adder

In the circuit of a serial adder (below), what exactly is the function of the D flip-flop? Since its characteristic equation is \$Q^+ = D\$, couldn't it be simply removed (replaced with the wire) without changing anything since the present \$C_{out}\$ will still go to the next \$C_{in}\$?

[image: Serial Adder]

Answer (score 2):

You need the \$C_{in}\$ to be the information from the previous operation. If you put a cable, then the \$C_{in}\$ would be constantly changing while the new data propagates through the gates of the adder and it wouldn't represent the previous \$C_{out}\$ anymore.

Comment: Yes, I think I got it. Also, it wouldn't be possible to get the initial value of \$C_{in}\$ without the reset of the D flip-flop (?)

Comment: That's right. You need to reset the FF before starting to calculate